# How to delete a CCNode in sprite builder through Xcode

Tags: xcode, spritebuilder, ccnode

i am making an angry birds game. At the moment i have 3 birds to the side of the screen. Each time i fire a bird i want to delete one of the animations. How do can I delete a CCNode in sprite builder through Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have code connections to the bird animations, you can simply remove them from the scene when a bird is launched. If self is the scene the animations are in:

```
[self removeChild:birdAnimation];
```